# Unable to connect to MySQL 8 from Python 3.8

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am using the following guidelines to connect to MySql8 from my Python code

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

When I enter my connection details, I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

I do not know what the issue could be? The link clearly does not talk about any security or the "Authentication plugin".

Would appreciate any help possible

Many Thanks

Comment: OK. I have managed to establish the connection from console and 'Jupyter lab' but continue to get the error in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted!! I just had to provide the mysql driver to Python. Adding to PyCharm or the any IDE is not a solution per se.

This is what I had to do:

```
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had installed the wrong pip package. I had installed `mysql-connector` when in reality I needed `mysql-connector-python`.

```
pip3 uninstall mysql-connector
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

After I had the correct package, I did not get the error.